# Firebase v9 modular.. no need to export auth, store etc. or create instances?

Tags: firebase, authentication, module, initialization, create-react-app

I use firebase v9 inside a create-react-app program.
I initialized the different parts like this:

```
import { initializeApp } from "@firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "@firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth } from "@firebase/auth";

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const firestore = getFirestore();
```

however, is there a need to initialize and export auth and firestore (and maybe others) at all?
because the utility function getAuth, getFirestore etc. used inside other components return me an instantiated corresponding auth and firestore already, so no need to create them in the first place? And how is this possible at all?

e.g inside my LoginComponent:

```
//import { auth } from '../../index'  //no need to import
import { getAuth} from 'firebase/auth'
const auth = getAuth() // continue with auth, its already set up with your config?!
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)...
```

Comment: Either way works. You could argue that exporting the instances is a bit more performant since it's not calling the function each time.

Comment: ok so I assume that in the firebase library, those instances get somehow created and cached somewhere behind the scenes with my firebase configuration provided?

Answer (score 1):

By the [looks of it](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/cdada6c68f9740d13dd6674bcb658e28e68253b6/packages/auth/src/platform_browser/index.ts#L40) the `getAuth` call is cached internally on the SDK (I'd be surprised if it wasn't) so calling it multiple times has no negative impact.

Either option you use will work fine. Personally I prefer exporting the instances myself.